# mapping over binary tree

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions

This is my function that map over a binary tree

```
type 'a btree = Empty
            |Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree

let rec treemap t f = match t with
  |Empty -> Empty
  |Node(root,left,right)-> Node(root f, treemap left f, treemap right f)
```

The type of the function has to be:

```
treemap: 'a btree -> ('a ->'b) -> 'b tree
```

but my function is returning this type instead:

```
val treemap : ('a -> 'b) btree -> 'a -> 'b btree
```

Comment: It would be best to also give the type constructor for `btree` in your source code, to make it easier for others to answer, even though it's possible to figure out what it should be.

Comment: I have added the type constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have gotten the function application switched around. `root f`should be `f root`:

```
let rec treemap t f = match t with
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (root, left, right) -> Node (f root, treemap left f, treemap right f)
```